# Как в folium сделать маркеры со своими значениями (ценами)?

Tags: python, yandex-maps-api, карты, folium

Хочу разместить на карте по координатам маркеры, каждый маркер должен отображать определённую стоимость на товар по своему адресу. Как можно сделать примерно такие маркеры как на скриншоте?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Яндекса есть свой пример создания маркеров https://codesandbox.io/embed/v6fhck?initialpath=vanilla.html&module=vanilla.html Как это в folium реализовать не подскажу.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью пользовательских маркеров, используя метод DivIcon:

```
import folium
from folium.features import DivIcon

m = folium.Map(location=(53.8747,27.4768), zoom_start=16)
locations = [[53.8730, 27.4712, 12.5], [53.8752, 27.4728, 15.4]]

for loc in locations:
    folium.map.Marker(
    location=loc[:2],
    icon=DivIcon(
        icon_size=(60,36),
        icon_anchor=(0,0),
        html=f"""<div style="font-size: 16pt; color: white">
        <g>
        <svg>
        <rect width="60" height="30" fill="blue" opacity=".9" rx="15"/>
        <text x="10" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="16" fill="white">{loc[2]}</text>
        </g>
        </svg></div>"""
        )
    ).add_to(m)
```

в этом примере в списке locations представлены подсписки с широтой, долготой и содержанием текста для каждой точки. Единственное - как подбирать размеры rect - экспериментируйте сами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]